# Win10 - Excel 2010 - Need macro to place hyphens between each letter of a single Hebrew word in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros

The goal is to separate each Hebrew letter of each word of the Tanach/Old Testament into separate cells. If I *manually* place hyphens between each letter in a word, then Text to Columns will place each letter in a cell with nikud/accents intact. [For the project, the letters will then be vertically placed into the form.]

I found a macro that nicely places hyphens between English word letters; however, it places hyphens even between Hebrew markings.

```
א-ֲ-ש-ׁ-ַ-ל-ּ-ֵ-֖-ם

נ-ְ-ד-ָ-ר-ֶ-֑-י-ך-ָ
```

https://excel.tips.net/T009633_Adding_Dashes_between_Letters.html

```
Sub AddDashes1()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim C As Integer

    For Each Cell In Selection
        sTemp = ""
        For C = 1 To Len(Cell)
            sTemp = sTemp + Mid(Cell, C, 1) + "-"
        Next
        Cell.Value = Left(sTemp, Len(sTemp) - 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, I don't know anything about writing code. Is there a way to tell the macro to only place hyphens between Hebrew letters plus maqqef, paseq, sof-pasuq - and ignore nikud/accents? (Any numbers won't be retained.)

‎7 ‏אַךְ־בְּצֶ֤לֶם׀

לֵאלֹהִֽים׃פ

After manually entering hyphens for several chapters of Job...an easier, softer way would be much appreciated. :)